# Estimating Column Size

Tags: mysql

This is what I found in the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/integer-types.html):

[image: storage explanation]

Can you help me interpret the data storage of this table?

Let's say I create a table like this:

```
create table test.test_1(

    value_1 tinyint,
    value_2 smallint,
    value_3 mediumint

)

insert into test.test_1(value_1, value_2, value_3) values(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3);
```

Are the following statements true if we sum up the data storage in each column:

- value_1 total size = 3 bytes
- value_2 total size = 6 bytes
- value_3 total size = 9 bytes

I understand how to find the total data storage if the column is a string data type, but how do I do this if the data if of the integer or numeric variety?

Comment: Test by inserting a few million rows, determine the data size, then work backwards. `SHOW TABLE STATUS` can help. There's additional overhead not related to any specific column, plus the cost of any indexes.

Comment: I was looking for more like select data_storage(column) from table

Comment: I did a search on Show Table Status and did not get accurate results. When searching some documentation, it says that that statement is unreliable. Do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: Some of the information it shows is accurate, and other information is guesses bawsed on those numbers. To calculate number of rows, for example, it takes total data size and divides by average row wise, the result of which is often way wrong, though the source numbers are correct.